# Android - Place a video at an arbitrary point on a playfield

Tags: java, android, video

I need help to place a video at an arbitrary point on a playfield.

I am porting a game which takes place on a playfield - background with animated sprites superimposed. It's working fine.

The activity does a

```
// Set full screen view
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Off that, I run a View on which all the action takes place. The playfield adjusts in size and offset, depending on screen size and orientation. All that's working fine, and I scale the sprites and their positions accordingly.

But sometimes, I need to place a borderless video on top of an existing background at various specific points in the playfield, and everything I read in stackoverflow is about the video itself and not how to position it. Can anyone help? Where should I start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Ah... It appears that I wanted AbsoluteLayout, which became deprecated in 2009. There is, however, more than one way to skin a cat. I just have to work a bit harder.